# Spring Security with REST

Tags: spring, security, rest

I have a small problem at the moment. The problem is that my web service is RESTful. Consequently, I need a stateless session for Spring Security in order not to break REST conception. I want to get the current user information and since my Spring Security session is stateless I don't know how. I also wanted to use @PreAuthorized annotations, but, now, it's impossible too for the reasons, I wrote above. Honestly, I'm new to REST services and I would be grateful for a piece of advice.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is in JSESSIONID. Spring use it as token in security filter chain to get `UserDetails`. But it's not good practice to use JSESSIONID for REST.

Briefly:

I suppose you should use [Spring OAuth/OAuth2](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) for authorization. You will have to configure `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. Then you will be able authenticate your user -> obtain *access_token* and *refresh_token*. After that you can use *access_token* for your REST requests, for example as *HTTP header Authorization: Bearer access_token*. When *access_token* become expired you should use *refresh_token* to refresh it. As usually you will be able to access `UserDetails` via `SecurityContextHolder`.

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: Ok. But I'm trying to avoid using SecurityContextHolder. Each request must be stateless and no data about previous requests should be stored on the server. Extracting data via SecurityContextHolder implies that I have the data on the server side.

Comment: But you want information about current user? If yes, then in case of oauth the trick is in relation between the access_token and the user. You don't need to know about previous request, It's like you send user name in each request but in more secure way. You able to use SecurityContextHolder just because Spring complete work for you, it just take access_token from request and populate SecurityContext with user principals from TokenStore.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. Now, I almost understood what you meant. I read a few similar topics and some people claim that, in this case, I should implement my custom filter. Inside the method doFilter() I should extract UserDetails from the token. Then I should put UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken into my SecurityContext. But I still have no idea how to extarct the user from the token. Does the fact that I can exctract the user from the token mean that I formed the token by my custom rules before?

Comment: No - if you use Spring OAuth/OAuth2. Spring will generate the tokens for you and put them into token store (In memmory or JDBC based) with credentials. So, when you will come with the token Spring will able to extract credentials from TokenStore by the token. It's to long to explain here, but all what you need well documented there http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/ and there https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749 .